# Probabilities of passing courses (conditional probability)

Tags: probability

Jennifer estimates that her probablity of passing French is 0.7 and her probability of passing chemistry is 0.6. 
Determine the probability that Jennifer will:

1) Pass both French and Chemistry 
 2) Pass French but fail Chemistry 
 3) Fail both French and Chemistry.

Where do I start? Is this a tree or a Venn diagram? Here is what I have so far:

1) $P(c) + P (f) = 0.7-0.6 = 0.88$ for passing both

2) $0.7+0.6-0.1 = 1.2$ pass French fail chemistry

3) $P(\mathrm{not \ passing\ both}) = 1-0.88 = 0.12$

Comment: Hello and welcome to Mathematics SE. A few remarks on your question: your title is not really clear as to what is the underlying problem you are trying to solve. Furthermore, your notation and layout could be improved. I will now try to do this for you :)

Comment: We need information about the accuracy of Jennifer's self-assessments in order to answer the question.

Comment: This is a probability questions and the question is exactly how I have written it. Jennifer estimates that her probablity of passing French is 0.7 and her probability of passing chemistry is 0.6. Determine the probability that Jennifer will: 

1) Pass both French and Chemistry 2) Pass French but fail Chemistry 3) Fail both French and Chemistry.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming her estimates are correct (or viewing the probabilities form Jennifer's point of view) we can answer these questions under the assumption that passing French or Chemistry are independent events. So simply said, whether or not Jennifer passes her French course, this has no impact on whether or not she will succeed in Chemistry.

Let's start from the basics. We know that the probability of her passing French is $0.7$ and $0.6$ for chemistry. Let's call $F$ the event that she passes French and $C$ for passing Chemistry. We have four possible events.

A. Pass French and pass Chemistry

B. Pass French but fail Chemistry

C. Fail French and pass Chemistry

D. Fail French and fail Chemistry

Now as you can see your questions correspond to finding the probabilities of events $A,B$ and $D$.
Assuming independence we multiply the relevant probabilities to obtain:
$$P(A)=P(F \cap C)=P(F)\cdot P(C)=0.7\cdot 0.6=0.42$$
Now for your second question we fail chemistry so the probability becomes:
$$P(B)=P(F \cap (\mathrm{not \ } C))=P(F)\cdot P(\mathrm{not \ } C)=P(F)\cdot (1-P(C))=0.7 \cdot (1-0.6)=0.28$$

Now for your final question:
$$P(D)=P((\mathrm{not \ } F)\cap (\mathrm{not \ } C))=P(\mathrm{not \ } F)\cdot P(\mathrm{not \ } C)=(1-P(F))\cdot (1-P(C))=0.12$$

Comment: Thank you now I understand

Comment: Fail French and Chemistry, can you show me the numbers you used.  Not sure why it wouldn't be 0.28 X 0.18 (Fail Chemistry X Fail French)?

Comment: I can explain why, but it might be more insightful to you if you tell me more specifically why it should be $0.28 \cdot 0.18$ so I can see what your reasoning is and try to solve from the root cause.